# Extract index of Non duplicate elements in python list

Tags: python, algorithm, search

I have a list:

```
input = ['a','b','c','a','b','d','e','d','g','g']
```

I want index of all elements except duplicate in a list.

```
output = [0,1,2,5,6,8]
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem. what have you tried? where did you run into problems?

Answer (score 5):

You should iterate over the enumerated list and add each element to a set of "seen" elements and add the index to the output list *if* the element hasn't already been seen (is not in the "seen" set).

Oh, the name `input` overrides the built-in `input()` function, so I renamed it `input_list`.

```
output = []
seen = set()
for i,e in enumerate(input_list):
    if e not in seen:
        output.append(i)
        seen.add(e)
```

which gives `output` as `[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 8]`.

---

**why use a set?**

You could be thinking, why use a set when you could do something like:

```
[i for i,e in enumerate(input_list) if input_list.index(e) == i]
```

which would work because `.index` returns you the index of the first element in a list with that value, so if you check the index of an element against this, you can assert that it is the first occurrence of that element and filter out those elements which aren't the first occurrences.

However, this is not as efficient as using a set, because `list.index` requires Python to iterate over the list until it finds the element (or doesn't). This operation is `O(n)` complexity and since we are calling it for every element in `input_list`, the whole solution would be `O(n^2)`.

On the other hand, using a set, as in the first solution, yields an `O(n)` solution, because checking if an element is `in` a set is complexity `O(1)` (average case). This is due to how sets are implemented (they are like lists, but each element is stored at the index of its hash so you can just compute the hash of an element and see if there is an element there to check membership rather than iterating over it - note that this is a vague oversimplification but is the idea of them).

Thus, since each check for membership is `O(1)`, and we do this for each element, we get an `O(n)` solution which is much better than an `O(n^2)` solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a something like this, checking for counts (although this is computation-heavy):

```
indexes = []
for i, x in enumerate(inputlist):
    if (inputlist.count(x) == 1
        and x not in inputlist[:i]):
        indexes.append(i)
```

This checks for the following:

1. if the item appears only once. If so, continue...
2. if the item hasn't appeared before in the list up till now. If so, add to the results list

Comment: This would give the indices of the unique elements, not the first index at which an element appears, as requested in the question.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't mind indexes of the last occurrences of duplicates instead and are using Python 3.6+, here's an alternative solution:

```
list(dict(map(reversed, enumerate(input))).values())
```

This returns:

```
[3, 4, 2, 7, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner using `zip` and `reversed`

```
>>> input = ['a','b','c','a','b','d','e','d','g','g']
>>> sorted(dict(zip(reversed(input), range(len(input)-1, -1, -1))).values())
[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is missing a `pandas` solution.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> inp = ['a','b','c','a','b','d','e','d','g','g']
>>> 
>>> pd.DataFrame(list(enumerate(inp))).groupby(1).first()[0].tolist()
[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another version, using a side effect in a list comprehension.

```
>>> xs=['a','b','c','a','b','d','e','d','g','g']
>>> seen = set()
>>> [i for i, v in enumerate(xs) if v not in seen and not seen.add(v)]
[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 8]
```

The list comprehension filters indices of values that have not been seen already. 
The trick is that `not seen.add(v)` is always true because `seen.add(v)` returns `None`. 
Because of short circuit evaluation, `seen.add(v)` is performed if and only if  `v` is not in seen, adding new values to `seen` on the fly.

At the end, seen contains all the values of the input list.

```
>>> seen
{'a', 'c', 'g', 'b', 'd', 'e'}
```

Note: **it is usually a bad idea to use side effects in list comprehension**, 
but you might see this trick sometimes.